# Help with tracking sub domain

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, web-applications

I currently have my app's marketing/external website on the root level, e.g. `http://example.com`

My web app itself is hosted at: `http://app.example.com`

What's the best strategy to set-up Google Analytics tracking for both of them? Should I create a separate web property? Also, what's the difference between creating a new web property and a new profile?

UPDATE: I would want to be able to track conversion from a page on the root domain to a sign-up page on the app sub-domain.

Answer (score 2):

I would use separate profiles for both the root and sub-domain. To answer you're secondary question, [there](http://www.phpjunkyard.com/php-text-hit-counter.php) [are](http://www.developingwebs.net/phpclass/hitcounter.php) [a](http://www.doheth.co.uk/codelair/php-mysql/hit-counter) [number](http://www.phpjunkyard.com/php-graphical-hit-counter.php) of simple php hit counters for you to use for the conversion from a specific URL that will probably serve your purposes better than with some kind of over-kill webapp.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one Google Analytics account, setup Goals and Funnels from your signup page to your thank you page. Also setup event tracking on all the form fields to track where people are abandoning the form and improve on it's design. With one profile you could also go into your Content and view by title or url and see the traffic source

Answer (score 0):

checkout [google analytics tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html) - look for _addItem()

Comment: could you be more specific? and add a link?

Comment: @Christofian it's _addItem() not setItem(): http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html

Comment: if you could edit your answer to correct that and add the link that would be great. Also, that looks like you would use it for ecomerce, which doesn't seem to be what the asker is looking for (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Christofian you're right that it's under the "eCommerce" section - but he can use this option to track different pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new property under the same profile so that both the sites (your marketing site and your web app are available under the same profile).

Tracking conversion over multiple subdomains is possible in GA and you can easily set up a Google Analytics Goal for the same.